# Can't exclude logback-classic dependency from dropwizard project

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j, dropwizard

I am working a number of projects that are using Dropwizard 0.8.2 with sfl4j-api 1.7.12 for logging. Our chosen implementation for slf4j is slf4j-log4j12, but we are having a problem with multiple implementations present in the project.

When trying to run it, it complains that multiple SLF4J bindings are present. One is ours, the other is logback-classic which is coming from the dropwizard-jackson dependency.

The problem is when we try to exclude logback-classic from the dependencies we get the following error when trying to start the server:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/filter/ThresholdFilter
    at io.dropwizard.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Is there any way that people know of to use log4j with Dropwizard?

Comment: This is now doable. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52067963/1778461.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can remove logback from the runtime classpath and make dropwizard use some other logging implementation (without modifying dropwizard's code). As we can see, `io.dropwizard.Application`'s static initializer [calls](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v0.8.2/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/Application.java#L20) `io.dropwizard.logging.LoggingFactory.bootstrap()`, and [`LoggingFactory`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v0.8.2/dropwizard-logging/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/logging/LoggingFactory.java) directly uses classes from logback, so `LoggingFactory` class just won't initialize without logback.